# Provide @ExampleObject for @ArraySchema of byte[]

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a GET method with this signature:
`ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocuments` and I want to provide an example of what a response should look like. This is what I have:

```
@Operation(summary = "some stuff",
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
            content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "byte")),
                examples = @ExampleObject(value = "[104, 111, 108, 97]"))
```

But I am getting the following:

> "0" property type must be string                               paths./documents.get.responses[200].content.application/json.example[0]

How do I specify in swagger en example for a byte array response?